# I want to extract coefficients of a linear formula. But my code didn't work

Tags: expression-test

I want to extract coefficients of a linear formula and I wrote the following function. But it didn't work.

```
f = Subscript[x, 1] + Times[2, Subscript[x, 2]]
extractCoeff[f_] := Table[If[Head[f[[i]]] == Times, f[[i, 1]], 1], {i, Length[f]}]
```

What should I do?
Please tell me.

Comment: Use `SameQ` (`===`); `Equal` (`==`) is not intended for the comparison you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, J. M. is somewhat okay. I changed my code, my code is OK now.